# Detecting a double tap gesture only once

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, xcode6

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *aTouch in touches) {
        if (aTouch.tapCount >= 2) {
            // The view responds to the tap
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the code above to detect double tap gesture; however, how can I set the code to happen only once?

In other words, when you **tap once**, the character jumps. When you tap twice in quick succession, the character will double jump. But how do you set the taps in a way that the character will not continuously double jump and go higher off the single-view without initially **taping once**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach of achieving this is by declaring a global `bool` variable and set its value once the double tap has been detected!

Something like this:

```
@interface MyViewController()
{
    bool isTapped;
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    for (UITouch *aTouch in touches) {
        if (aTouch.tapCount >= 2) {
            if(!isTapped) {
                // The view responds to the tap
                isTapped = YES;
            }
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps and also just take one flag and set it yes or no accordingly:-

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
tapRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = //Up to you;
[self.someView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```